# How can one “split” an Excel (.xlsx) file that contains multiple sheets into separate sheet[n].xlsx on my Mac?

Tags: microsoft-excel, xlsx

I want to acknowledge first before I ask this question that this question has been answered before [here](https://superuser.com/questions/561923/how-can-one-split-an-excel-xlsx-file-that-contains-multiple-sheets-into-sep) but I still cannot get it to work with my Mac. I see others had success in the thread mentioned but I have had none.

I have the developer tag turned on in Excel, I open the Visual Basic Editor, I create a module for 'ThisWorkbook', paste the code below, and hit the play button.

This definitely runs the code because I end up with each sheet as a new file in the relevant folder, but each file is a TEXTEDIT file that has a "-locked" in the file name. Upon opening, the file appears empty.

CODE USED:

```
Sub CreateNewWBS()
Dim wbThis As Workbook
Dim wbNew As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strFilename As String
Set wbThis = ThisWorkbook

    For Each ws In wbThis.Worksheets
        strFilename = wbThis.Path & "/" & ws.Name
        ws.Copy
        Set wbNew = ActiveWorkbook
        wbNew.SaveAs strFilename
        wbNew.Close
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Files are being saved as seen in the following image:
[saving as TEXTEDIT files with -locked in name once opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOh5p.png)

Comment: Try: `wbNew.SaveAs Filename:=strFilename, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook`

Comment: Do you mean to add this in place of the current `wbNew.SaveAs strFilename`?

Comment: yes, that is what I mean

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad, no luck there. The result is the same.